# I am forming an if-else code in python and the output should be Correct Answer , but It's printing the else part of the code, I don't know why

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, if-statement

The code:

```
user_answer = input("What is 8+13=")
answer = 21
if user_answer == answer:
    print("Correct answer!")
else:
    print("Try Again!")
```

Even if it takes input as 21, it prints the else part of the code

Answer (score 2):

The input function returns the entered text as a string, see [the API documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Then your code is comparing the string "21" to an integer value 21, comparing a string with an int will evaluate to false.

You could convert the string to an integer value (you can use [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)):

```
user_answer = input("What is 8+13")
answer=21
if int(user_answer) == answer:
    print("Correct answer!")
else:
    print("Try again!")
```

but this will raise an error if the input can't be converted to an int value. Alternatively convert the int to a string:

```
user_answer = input("What is 8+13")
answer=21
if user_answer == str(answer):
    print("Correct answer!")
else:
    print("Try again!")
```

Comment: that or str(answer) which would not throw an error if input was '21a' for instance. Could of couse have an input validator too.

Comment: @AntonvBR: yes, thanks. will edit that in.